# Add GitLab Group through API with https

Tags: php, ssl, https, gitlab

I managed to add a GitLab Group using the API v3.
Now we changed the Server from HTTP to HTTPS and i can't add Groups anymore.

The way it worked on HTTP was

```
$gitPostArray = array();
$gitPostArray["name"] = $groupName;
$gitPostArray["path"] = $groupPath;

$postdata = http_build_query($gitPostArray);
$opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $postdata
                 )
            );
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($this->connectionUrl . $path . '?private_token=' . $this->private_token, false, $context);

$objPost = json_decode($result);
```

But now it won't add my Groups.
I changed the line:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
$opts = array('https' =>
```

---

*EDIT* 2014-07-08:
oh, i found something interesting :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#74795
and
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#110158

i wrote

```
$opts = array ('https' => .....
```

but maybe it's

```
 $opts = array ('ssl' => ...
```

---

*EDIT* 2014-07-08 
Found a solution (scroll down)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24628159/59689

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Instead of using file_get_contents 
u have to "**fopen**" a stream and then use **stream_get_contents**.

the working solution is:

```
$postdata = http_build_query($postArray);

$opts = array(
   'http' =>
       array(
       'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
         )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$urlstream = fopen($this->connectionUrl . $path . '?private_token=' . $this->private_token, 'r', false, $context);

$result = stream_get_contents($urlstream);

$objPost = json_decode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error when you try to post or does it fail without any errors?

Also, is this a trusted certificate or self signed one?

Comment: It's a trusted certificate. The problem is, i have no direct access to the server because of our security-stuff... All things i try, i have to controll "remote" :-)
But if i enter the url with the parameters o don't get an error:

https://git.blablabladfasdfa.de/api/v3/groups?name=groupname_2010&path=groupnamepath_2010&private_token=uLTr4Pr1V4Te70Ken